# about xyplot-wpf y axis alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I do a project to show multi signal waves vertically arrangement。when the signal type is different（bool vs unsigned short）（means max value different）。the two signals y axis cant be aligned in x direction(because the max y value string occupy different space),something like this

[image]

I hope 2 solutions

1. the max y value text can be placed in the right of y axis
2. the max y value can be set to occupy same space(max value 1 occupy 5 characters padleft with empty，max value 65535 occupy 5 characters)

this is my code:

```
var series1 = new LineSeries { Title = serietitle, MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle };
var dateTimeAxis1 = new DateTimeAxis() { Minimum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now), Maximum = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)) };
//dateTimeAxis1.Title = "Time";
model.Axes.Add(dateTimeAxis1);
model.Series.Add(series1);
LinearAxis leftAxis = new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Left,
    AbsoluteMaximum= maxy,
    IsAxisVisible = true,  //
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = maxy,
    Title = "SigValue",//
    IsZoomEnabled = false,//

};
model.Axes.Add(leftAxis);
```

Comment: need someone help

Comment: You have shown your code and described what you need to accomplish... but what is your question?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  From [ask]: *Introduce the problem before you post any code... xplain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.*  It's not clear from your first paragraph what your problem is.  Might you [edit] to clarify the language please?